# Get bin directory of process

Tags: linux

I want to show only the directories where the binaries are installed. Like

```
/bin
```

for

```
/bin/ls
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
ps aux | awk '{print $11}' | grep -x -e "/.*"
```

But its displaying the filename too, and I dont want that, and example of the output:

> /usr/lib/firefox/firefox

But id like it like this:

> /usr/lib/firefox

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think these are the *working directories*... These are the directories where the binaries are located.

Comment: dirname /usr/lib/firefox/firefox will print /usr/lib/firefox

Comment: Do you want the working directory or the directory containing the executable? If the former, I'd look in the `/proc/<pid>` directory.  If the latter, try using `dirname` to strip the filename

Comment: @CommuSoft Yes sorry, I meant where the binaries are located, will edit my post.

Comment: @Jozo: well evidently that's not a huge problem, but please fix it since you will attract programmers that are looking for another application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command in order to extract the name of the directory is `dirname "path/to/file"`. Now as you probably see, it requires an argument (does not read from stdin). You can however use `xargs` to fix this:

```
xargs dirname
```

Now you simply need to add this at the end of your pipeline:

```
ps aux | awk '{print $11}' | grep -x -e "/.*" | xargs dirname
```

**Demo**

Ran this on my Linux machine:

```
$ ps aux | awk '{print $11}' | grep -x -e "/.*" | xargs dirname | head
/sbin
/lib/systemd
/lib/systemd
/sbin
/usr/sbin
/usr/sbin
/usr/sbin
/usr/sbin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
```

In order to make your command space-safe (a remark by @hek2mgl), you can use:

```
ps aux | awk '{print $11}' | grep -x -e "/.*" | xargs -I file dirname "file"
```

Mind this will have an impact on performance: whereas using `xargs dirname` without any flags would use the loop mechanism of `dirname` handling multiple parameters, and thus resulting in a tight loop, using the latter will spawn a `dirname` process for each line *individually*.

## More elegant way

Your program makes use of a lot of text processing, which can be tricky, error prone and furthermore sensitive to changes of the format (of `ps`,...). A less error prone way can be:

```
ps -A -o pid | xargs -I pid readlink "/proc/pid/exe" | xargs -I file dirname "file"
```

Comment: That's crap (question and answer). @CommuSoft Have you tried it (seriously)?

Comment: @hek2mgl: yes, ran it on my machine. Care to explain why you think it is crap. Expect someone with 62k+ reputation to be way much more informative. I was most disappointed.

Comment: @hek2mgl: please read the comment below the question, the OP is not asking the working directory.

Comment: First it is obvious that using `awk '{print $11}' | grep -x -e "/.*"` should be `awk '$11 ~ /^\//{print $11}`. (A 21.5k user should know that awk is capable of matching regexes)

Comment: Second. The command will obviously fail if a space occurs somewhere in the path.

Comment: Third. The regex `/.*` dismisses processes which have renamed themself - something that is pretty common for UNIX daemons. Take `lightdm` for example. It appears as `lightdm` without any path in ps. That's what I mean with "seriously". Please check `ps aux` output against `ps aux |  grep -x -e "/.*"`

Comment: I can add that the xargs solution worked perfectly for me, no issues.

Comment: @hek2mgl: (1) that would indeed be the case if I validated the question. The user only has a problem extracting the dirname, but no problem that you want to correct this; (2) spaces on a *nix* system? That's asking for trouble (one should never use spaces since indeed using them in program parameters is tricky); (3) it is more efficient since `dirname` is only called once, so you somehow "use the parameter interpretation mechanism" to set the loop more tight; (4) In case you've messed up your file system with spaces, you can use for instance `xargs -I file dirname "file"`.

Comment: @hek2mgl: but I'm happy you minded commenting anyway. Only wondering why not doing this *en passant*, like the French use to say.

Comment: @Jozo `xargs` is not the problem here. And even if we say that spaces in the path are out of scope, there are still  processes which appear simply like `lightdm` or `nginx-worker` or whatever, but without a path. The above command would miss them completely. IMHO (on Linux) you would need to get that information out of the `/proc` filesystem.

Comment: @hek2mgl: Updated the answer with a version using `proc`. You are correct that the way to fetch files in the question is a rather hacky solution, but given that works, using `xargs` can do the trick.

Comment: @CommuSoft +1 for the *More elegant way* ;) This looks much better! Nice one. But you see, still processes are missing!

Comment: @hek2mgl: don't get me wrong, comments on answers are great. But a simple "*this is crap*", is not a good way to get an answer improved ;).

Comment: Isn't it? But still the answer is not perfect. (and IMHO it is hard till impossible to give the right answer).. You miss some processes! (let's agree that kernel processes are out of scope)

Comment: @hek2mgl: not without additional comment on what you think needs to improved. And indeed the program is not perfect. Most shell scripts are not designed to be perfect anyway. That's why most people call them *scripts*: used for fast prototyping and some simple stuff.